# Remote desktop via LAN cable, no router and other things

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, lan, remote-connection

I have two PCs, one is a Windows 7 desktop and another is Windows 10 laptop. I want to use remote desktop connection to connect to the Windows 7 desktop which is connected to the laptop with a LAN cable, no router and other things. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to google it? I just did and the top result had the answer.

Comment: @John It's barely difficult at all. Also, modern consumer-grade hardware doesn't care about crossovers anymore, it can detect when a crossover is needed and internally cross wires as needed.

Comment: @John My cable has a stamp with follwing things written on it, 'D-Link TYPE CM 24AWG 75°C ETL VERIFIED TO EIA / TIA - 568C.2.1 CAT 6 UTP PATCH CABLE.'                  I have tried this using a router but I want to accomplish this without a router due to specific reasons.

Comment: @gronostaj  I have tried to google it but  most of them are either using router or are with some kind of Pre-setup which I can't do.

Comment: [Google results for "windows lan without router"](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+lan+without+router), ["windows direct lan"](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+direct+lan)